# Dreamweaver CS5.5 and PHP -generated- code

Tags: php, dreamweaver

I'm currently using Dreamweaver CS5.5 and I 'd like some information about the PHP code that Dw generates, 'cause I find it a little bit confusing and find it a little bit difficult to understand.

1st. About the Authorization or the  login script that dw generates. Do I have to sanitize the given username or encrypt/hash the password  before doing the check with the ones that are in database, or Dreamweaver does already this for me? If I have to do it by myself where exactly can I apply my own code?

2nd. When creating a query from the bindings, Dreamweaver also generates a GetSQLValueString function which, to tell the truth, confuses me a lot. If I remove this code completely, and keep only the query( or queries in case i want to have more than one), will this have any effect on the rest functionality of the page? Or what if I put it in a seperate file and inlude it in the pages i want to?

3rd. I've also noticed that creates some folders like _mmServerScripts, _notes in the site. Is it also ok if I delete them from the site, or will have an effect on my code?

And one last thing. When I sometimes type an if statement like this:

```
<?php if(a_condtition): ?>

<p>Hello</p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

I get the syntax error highlight. Is this somekind of bug?

Comment: You've asked 12 questions and never got a satisfactory answer. Why do you keep coming back?

Comment: `a_condtition` is not a variable

Comment: Stop using DW to generate code, it's useless in almost every respect for that. Other than being a very expensive text editor with nice auto complete functions it's crap. Get a good text editor Notepadd++ for example and read some beginner tutorials. This is EXACTLY the problem with wysiwyg editors. The people that use them never understand what they're doing so they can't fix the problems that arise. Your last question is pointless without real code. Your code there will work without a syntax error, so obviously when you get that "sometimes" you're doing something else wrong.

Comment: all of that is true.  to get the little red error notification to go away tho, just put a dollar sign ($) infront of the php variable ($a_condition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Dreamweaver assumes that the password is in the database in plain text. It dates back to the days when people habitually made that mistake.
2. GetSQLValueString is Dreamweaver's simplistic way of cleansing strings to prevent injection attacks. It works pretty well.
3. The various extra directories that DW makes are partly for versioning and access; and partly for configuring the test environment. Remove them from the live site by filtering them in FTP.
4. The if statement you show is not recognised as syntactically correct in DW

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So if i understand right those you told me in 1) i had to do it all my self and 2) its useful though, but i can remove it  completely to apply my own code if i want to (??)

Comment: That's about it. You can use the DW code but you need to insert the extra step that hashes your password. For 2, yes, you can just write/call your own function

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php if($a_condtition)
{
    echo '<p>Hello</p>';
}?>
```